# Is it possible to pass multiple toml config files in ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

As of now in the ballerina; I have seen most of the sample listed in the document has a single toml file for the configuration. Is it possible to pass multiple toml files?

If it is possible; It will be very useful to deal with multiple connectors and store the values in different files.

Comment: Having just a single config file was a conscious decision. The idea was to eliminate the complexity and confusion surrounding multiple config files and make it simple and straight forward. Did you come across any issues with using the same config file for all connectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to specify multiple files with the `--config` flag at the moment. Please open a [GitHub](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues) issue and open a discussion.

The Ballerina Config API looks up values from sources in the following order.

1. command-line parameters
2. environment variables
3. configuration file

You can extend the config API by integrating with your own configuration store as well.